# How to update counter field on the inverse side in many-to-many relation in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, many-to-many, sonata-admin

I have two enteties User and Category, which are connected each other by many-to-many relation.

```
manyToMany:
    categories:
      targetEntity: Category
      joinTable:
        name: users_categories
        joinColumns:
          user_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
        inverseJoinColumns:
          category_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
```

In my UserAdmin.php (I'm using Sonata Admin and Sonata User bundles) they are handled by this field:

```
->add('categories', 'sonata_type_model', array('required' => false, 'expanded' => false, 'multiple' => true, 'label' => 'Chose your categories'))
```

Now I need to add extra field to my Category entity - user_counter, which store number of users, linked with it. It should be updated every time User add, update or delete his relations with Categories.

One idea was to make method in User entity which would get his categories before saving admin form, comparing them to current input and then making decision (categories counter to make +1 or -1). And switch on this method by lifecycleCallbacks (prePersist and preUpdate).

The problem: my code will get all User categories and compare them to current input on each form saving. How I can  avoid such overhead? Maybe there is another solution for this task?

Thank you for help.

Comment: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/cookbook/aggregate-fields.html .. On another note, you should also improve your accepted answer rate on stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you for link, Mike. I read it and if I realized everything right  I don't need to implement this field (user_counter) in Categories, but should make a method getUsersCount in Category entity which would count users with this category? Then, I should use this method in my UserAdmin class, when user make changes in his  linked categories on lifecycleCallbacks method? How I could detect that user make changes in categories?

Comment: But what if my app has a page, on which I show all the categories and their subcategories with the number of users, like:

Comment: But what if my app has a page, on which I show all the categories and their subcategories with the number of users, like: Category 1 (252), Subcategory 1 (140) and so on. There will be more than 50 categories on this page. I think that count() for each category will be very expensive for app performance.

Comment: See my answer.  I'm also editing the answer to include a doctrine listener alternative.

Answer (score 2):

One way you could keep track is to modify your collection methods in your entity.  For instance:

```
/*
 * @ORM\Column(name="user_counter", type="integer")
 */
 protected $user_counter;

public function addUser(User $user) 
{
    $this->users[] = $user;
    $this->user_counter++;
}

public function removeUser(User $user)
{
    $this->users->remove($user);
    $this->user_counter--;
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't need the counts in the database, just do a $category->getUsers()->count();

Edit:

If you want to use an event listener to track this instead of modifying your entity setters, use a combination of `$unitOfWork->getScheduledCollectionUpdates()` and `getDeleteDiff()` and `getInsertDiff()`.

Comment: The problem here is that I don't have methods to interact with users in Category entity. Many-to-many relation is set in User entity. I suppose, that I should make this counter in addCategorie and removeCategorie of Category entity and manualy update it?

Comment: On edit: thank you for hint! I'll try to use it in User entity (I think).

Comment: Yeah, you could.  Or just add the inversed relation in category and add the setters/getters.